# Call webhook using react js

Tags: reactjs, webhooks

Hello everybody is there a way to get the response from a postback webhook using react js?

if yes, can you provide an example?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call a webhook and handle its response in a React JS application. In React, you can use JavaScript's fetch API or libraries like Axios to make HTTP requests. Here's a basic example using the fetch API in a React component. This example assumes you are making a request to the webhook and expecting a JSON response:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function WebhookComponent() {
    const [webhookResponse, setWebhookResponse] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const callWebhook = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('actual URL of the webhook', {
                    method: 'POST', // Specify the method
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set Content-Type header
                        // Add other headers if required
                    },
                    // No body is specified since you want to make a POST request without a body
                });
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                setWebhookResponse(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
                setWebhookResponse(null);
            }
        };

        callWebhook();
    }, []); 

    return (
        <div>
            {webhookResponse ? (
                <div>Response: {JSON.stringify(webhookResponse)}</div>
            ) : (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, only one more question, this webhook its only sending a json object, so i do not need to send anything, how can i do that? same with fetch api?

Comment: have updated code

Comment: I test it like in the update, but it says method not allowed as it tried to perform a get, so the webhook is a post, it sends a json via post and i need to receive it.

Comment: Its a postback webhook, so i cant send a post, get, cause if i use a post with no body, it says it cant perform runtime binding on a null reference and with get it throws a not allowed method. I also tried websocket, but im not being able to connect to the endpint.

Comment: I've also tried that, but also got same error message. Sorry if i did not explain it well before. So actually i send a payment, and then the "company" sends a json object to a webhook (endpoint i provided with the code to get the json) and then i will need to get that information sent to that webhook and display it.